# If X and Y are iid $Ge(\lambda)$ then a few questions on max{X,Y}

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X $ and $Y$ be independent RVs with common geometric PMF :$$P \{X=k\} = \lambda {(1- \lambda)}^k , k=0,1,2,\ldots ; 0 < \lambda < 1$$

Now let, $M = \text{max{X,Y}}$. So I was trying to find the followings:

(a) The joint distribution of M and X.

(b) The marginal distribution of M.

(c) The conditional distribution of X, given M.

I only know the definitions in the problem and am finding to solve the problem to be extremely hard, so please provide an answer and help me learn nad understand the problem. Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: A little help : $M \leq x$ implies $X,Y\leq x$.

Comment: I know that much and also tried to compute it, but I got stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each nonnegative integer $k$, we have
$$
\{M=k\} = \{X=k\}\cup\{Y=k\}.
$$
We compute
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(M=k) &= \mathbb P\left(\{X=k\}\cup\{Y=k\}\right)\\
&= \sum_{j=0}^k \mathbb P(X=j)\mathbb P(Y=k) + \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \mathbb P(X=k)\mathbb P(Y=j)\\
&= \sum_{j=0}^k \lambda^2(1-\lambda)^{j+k} + \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \lambda^2(1-\lambda)^{j+k}\\
&= \lambda^2(1-\lambda)^k\left(1-(1-\lambda)^{k+1}\right) + \lambda^2(1-\lambda)^k\left(1-(1-\lambda)^k\right)\\
&= \lambda(1-\lambda)^k\left(2-(1-\lambda)^k(2-\lambda)\right).
\end{align}

To compute the joint distribution of $(M,X)$, first consider $0\leqslant j<k$:
$$
\mathbb P(M=k,X=j) = \mathbb P(Y=k,X=j) = \lambda^2(1-\lambda)^{j+k},
$$
and then $k$:
$$
\mathbb P(M=k,X=k) = \mathbb P(X=k,Y\leqslant k) = \lambda(1-\lambda)^k\left(1-(1-\lambda)^{k+1}\right).
$$
The conditional distribution of $X$ given $M$ can be computed by the definition of conditional probability:

$$
\mathbb P(X=j\mid M=k) = \frac{\mathbb P\left(\{X=j\}\cap\{M=k\}\right)}{\mathbb P(M=k)}.
$$

Comment: I don't understand how one gets the 4 th line from 3 rd line in the first part and also why you're choosing the second sum in the very first part upto k-1 not upto k. Can you please explain?

Comment: To not double count the case where $X=Y=k$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thanks, I have corrected it.